# JS assemble sets of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have elements like this:

```
[1, A. data]
[2, B, data]
[3, C, data]
[4, A, data]
[5, B, data]
[6, A, data]
```

or the same  split by category

```
[1, A. data]
[4, A, data]
[6, A, data]

[2, B, data]
[5, B, data]

[3, C, data]
```

I want an array that contains:  A, A+B, A+C, A+B+C.

Two ways: Start with all elements and remove OR start separated and join:

```
var startArr = 
[
[ 1, 'a', 'data'], 
[ 2, 'b', 'data'],
[ 3, 'c', 'data'],
[ 4, 'a', 'data'], 
[ 5, 'b', 'data'], 
[ 6, 'a', 'data'], 
[ 7, 'a', 'data'], 
[ 8, 'c', 'data'], 
[ 9, 'a', 'data'] 
];

//1.1 Filter
function checkCat(el) {
    return el[1] != 'a';
}
newArr = startArr.filter(checkCat);

//1.2 Remove elements in reverse loop
var i;
for (i = startArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (startArr[i][1] == 'b' || startArr[i][1] == 'c') {
    startArr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

How do you think ? Thank you.

```
var startA = [
    [ 1, 'a', 'data'],
    [ 4, 'a', 'data'],
    [ 6, 'a', 'data'], 
    [ 7, 'a', 'data'],
    [ 9, 'a', 'data'] 
];

var startB = [
    [ 2, 'b', 'data'],
    [ 5, 'b', 'data']
]

var startC = [
    [ 3, 'c', 'data'],
    [ 8, 'c', 'data']
]

//2.1 Join and sort
arrMid = startA.concat(startC);
arrFinal = arrMid.sort(function(a, b){ return a[0]-b[0]});

//2.2 Find index and insert at it in a loop
function whereIsMyPlace(element) {
    return element[0] >= val ;
}

function putInPlace(item, index) {
    val = item[0];
    myPlace = startA.findIndex(whereIsMyPlace);
    startA.splice(myPlace, 0, item); 
}

startB.forEach(putInPlace);
startC.forEach(putInPlace);
```

Edit: [1, A, data],   1 - id , A - category, data = some data.

So in the end I want an array that contains all elements of category like A or combination of categories like "A and B" , "A and C" or "A and B and C". (this is different every time based on input).

And that array sorted by id number.

My question is should I start with *all* elements in *one* array and remove the categories I don't need (examples 1.1 and 1.2).

OR do the oposite and start with the elements grouped in arrays based on their category, and make the final array by adding the necessary ones (examples 2.1 and 2.2).

Is it more clear?

Imagine you have to write a function that should take one parameter and is capable of outputing all the possible combinations (A, A+B, A+C, A+B+C) which mean an array that holds all elements of that category or categories. 
How would you design the whole thing? You have control.
Please look the example code (which is fully correct and  functional).

Comment: I don't understand how the result is computed. do you want to create all subsets that contain a certain item (A)?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: what do you mean by a + b + c? where do get this information from?

Comment: why not B or C as well?